# RStudio crashes with call to getURL in RCurl

Tags: r, rstudio, osx-yosemite, rcurl

I am using the latest stable release of R (3.2.0) with RStudio (0.98.1103) on Mac OS 10.10.3.

When calling `getURL` from the `RCurl` package RStudio terminates with a fatal error.

This **does not** happen when using R from the command line, only in RStudio.

```
library("RCurl")
getURL("http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/")
```

Checking the output of `sessionInfo()`, `system.file()`, and `.libPaths()` after `library("RCurl")` does indeed lead me to believe I am using the same version of R and RCurl in both scenarios.

Executing R from the command line:

```
> library("RCurl")
Loading required package: bitops
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.6 bitops_1.0-6  
> system.file()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/base"
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library"
```

and then from inside RStudio:

```
> library("RCurl")
Loading required package: bitops
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.6 bitops_1.0-6  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
> system.file()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/base"
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library"
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the output of `sessionInfo()`, `system.file()`, and `.libPaths()` after library(RCurl) lead you to believe you are using the same version of R and RCurl in both scenarios?

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes it does, please see above. I should add this does not happen on Linux and has only happened after upgrading my Mac OS to Yosemite and my R to the latest release.

Comment: This sounds like a problem for RStudio support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed with upgrading to Mac OS 10.10.5, RStudio Version 0.99.489 and the latest R 3.2.3